# Can "Archive the artifacts" be disabled in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, archive, artifact, disable

I'd like to disable the option for my Jenkins users to use the Post-build action "Archive the artifacts". We are planning on fully migrating artifact uploads to an Artifactory server. Can I somehow remove the option for "Archive the artifacts", somewhat like removing a plugin?